# Birt cross tab - disable column grouping

Tags: birt

When I use a crosstab;

```
col1 | col2 | col3
a    |  22  |  33
     |  77  |  44
     |  32  |  655
b    |  22  |  67
c    |  90  |  23
```

How can I force the cross tab to repeat 'a' on each line?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to create some sort of concatenated response, and base the 'group' on that column but then never display it;

i.e.

select col1 || col2 as concat_column, col1, col2, col3 from database

The group is then based on concat_column, with col1 and col2 nested in it. In the crosstab, the width of the first column is then set to 0.

It seems like you have to set the report to 'fixed layout' to fully hide column the 0 width column.